# Package lacks a "Version" or "Package-Version" error, even if the "Version" info exists

Tags: package, cask

After upgrading `cask` the error message changed.

```
Wrong type argument: sequencep, pinyin-mode
```

### Original Question

I want to use my `elisp` through `cask`.

But it failed with error:

```
Dependency pinyin-mode failed to install: Package lacks a "Version" or "Package-Version" header
```

There is a line `;; Version: 0.0.1` in my `*.el` file.
What am I doing wrong?

This is the file I want to load through `cask`.

https://github.com/ironsand/pinyin-mode/blob/master/pinyin-mode.el

## Environment

I installed `cask` by `brew install cask` in `MacOS`.

```
$ cask --version
0.8.1
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 25.3.1
$ which emacs
emacs: aliased to env HOME=/Users/ironsand/spacemacs emacs
$ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --version
GNU Emacs 25.2.1
```

Comment: `(package-buffer-info)` of `cask-20180119.1906` runs just fine on `pinyin-mode.el`. What version of `cask` do you use? Also please add the emacs version. That is important since `cask` uses `lisp-mnt.el` which is part of vanilla emacs.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I upgraded the `cask` to `cask 0.8.1_1`, then error changes `Wrong type argument: sequencep, pinyin-mode`. I'll search how to solve this problem.

Comment: If you are using EmacsForMacOSX you might want to check the `exec-path` variable. I had to manually set it up in my .emacs in order to allow Emacs to find the paths of some of the binaries installed with homebrew.